# How to add values to attribute added dynamically to property without attribute constructor(Reflection.Emit)

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, reflection.emit

I was able to add `Attribute` and pass it `values` by `constructor`.
But how to pass `values` when `Attribute` do not have `constructor` with appropriate parameters to pass.
e.g. How to add this `DisplayAttribute` `using` `Reflection.Emit`?

```
[Display(Order = 28, ResourceType = typeof(CommonResources), Name = "DisplayComment")]
```

Hope it clear enough what I'm trying to accomplish.
If not please ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use `CustomAttributeBuilder`. For example:

```
var cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(
    ctor, ctorArgs,
    props, propValues,
    fields, fieldValues
);
prop.SetCustomAttribute(cab);
```

(or one of the related overloads)

In your case, that looks (this is pure guesswork) something like:

```
var attribType = typeof(DisplayAttribute);
var cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(
    attribType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), // constructor selection
    new object[0], // constructor arguments - none
    new[] { // properties to assign to
        attribType.GetProperty("Order"),
        attribType.GetProperty("ResourceType"),
        attribType.GetProperty("Name"),
    },
    new object[] { // values for property assignment
        28,
        typeof(CommonResources),
        "DisplayComment"
    });
prop.SetCustomAttribute(cab);
```

Note I'm assuming that `Order`, `ResourceType` and `Name` are *properties*. If they are *fields*, there is a different overload.

Comment: Thats exacly what I'm looking for :) Will accept answer in 2 minutes. Thanks @Marc :)

Is it somewhere in specification? Could you provide a link to it?

Comment: @harry180 that depends on what you mean by "specification"; it certainly isn't in the language specification, because it has nothing to do with the language; it is in the framework documentation though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.customattributebuilder.aspx (note it goes all the way back to 1.1)